# How to debug programs using signals?

Tags: gdb, signals

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <signal.h>

static volatile sig_atomic_t being_debugged = 1;
static void int3_handler(int signo) { being_debugged = 0; }

int main()
{
        signal(SIGTRAP, int3_handler);
        __asm__ __volatile__("int3");
        if (being_debugged) {
        puts("No, I don't want to serve you.");
                while (1) {
            /* endless loop */ ;
        }
        }
        puts("Yes, real routines go here.");
        return 0;
}
```

The above will give different output when run inside/outside gdb,because gdb captures the sigtrap signal.

How to make my program behaves the same in gdb?

Comment: You are probably also looking at ptrace sigcall too. The code here will fail to debug GDB if someone set up its gdb to pass the sigtrap to the program. However, if you try to ptrace yourself, you won't succeed if you're running under GDB (already ptraced), and there is no way to prevent/hide this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

GDB will stop the inferior (being debugged) program when the inferior receives any signal.

If you simply `continue` from GDB, the signal will be "swallowed", which is not what you want.

You can ask GDB to continue the program *and* send it a signal with `signal SIGTRAP`.

You can also ask GDB to pass a given signal directly to the inferior, and not stop at all with `handle SIGTRAP nostop noprint pass` GDB command. You'll need to do that *before* you hit the first `SIGTRAP`.