# Terminate program hitting CTRL+C within GDB

Tags: gdb, mingw

My program is determined to stop its execution by hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in command window. By now, I have a critical error right in this stopping phase, so i want to debug with gdb.

Problem is, gdb redefines <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as its own interrupt and pauses the execution when hitted. How can I handle it that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> powers my programm off and gdb can catch the stack trace?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6008140/694576

Answer (score 72, accepted):

From the `(gdb)` prompt, type `signal SIGINT`. This will send (surprize) `SIGINT` to the program being debugged.

Alternatively, `handle SIGINT nostop print pass` will make GDB pass the signal straight to the inferior (being debugged) process.

Comment: Ctrl-Z works in GDB: it suspends the process and gets you to that `(gdb)` prompt.