# Handling signal keeping crash point

Tags: c++, crash, signals, posix, coredump

Folks, I would like to handle signals like SIGSEGV, but still crash the application so I can get a core dump.

On my approach, in my signal handler I unregister the signal handler so I can crash the application instead of getting into a loop, bellow follows a sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

void signalHandler( int signum )
{
   signal(SIGFPE, SIG_DFL);
   raise(signum); // <-- should I keep this line?
}

int main ()
{
   signal(SIGFPE, signalHandler);  

   int a, b=2, c=0;
   a=b/c;

   return 0;
}
```

Now to the question:

I'm not sure if I should keep that `raise` line. Doing some testing I've found out that if I keep it or not in both cases I get the gdb pointing to the offending line `a=b/c;`, however I don't quite get this.

It makes sense that if I don't call `raise` the offending line will be re-executed after the signal handler and thus I'll get the core dump that I expect, however if I manually call `raise` what I would expect is the offending line to be the line which is calling `raise`. Can someone put some light on this?

Comment: GDB stops when it sees a signal whether you handle it in your code or not. Digging up a nice quote for my answer found an existing potential dupe: [How to debug programes using signals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008140/how-to-debug-programes-using-signals)

Comment: Calling `abort()` terinates the execution with a core dump.