# Unable to catch SIGINT sent by CLion

Tags: c++, signals, clion

I am working on some network programming project using CLion. As I am using sockets, if I don't close cleanly the sockets and other networking objects I am using, then the program will block the port, and I will have to close it myself, using command lines.

It's pretty annoying, considering I would have to do this between every test. So I looked for the way CLion kills a program when you click on "stop", and I found out it sends a SIGINT signal, [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/run-tool-window.html) :

> Click this button to terminate the current process externally by means of the 
>   standard shutdown script.
>   Clicking the button once invokes soft kill allowing the application to
>   catch the SIGINT event and perform graceful termination (on Windows,
>   the Ctrl+C event is emulated). After the button is clicked once, it is
>   replaced with icon run tool window kill indicating that subsequent
>   click will lead to force termination of the application, e.g. on Unix
>   SIGKILL is sent.

Then, I have been trying to catch it, but for some reasons, it's not working.
So I tried creating a new project, in which I am just trying to catch `SIGINT` signal. Here is a very simple non-working example :

```
#include <iostream>

void signalHandling(int signal)
{
    std::cout << "Signal : " << signal << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    signal(SIGINT, signalHandling);
    while (1)
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

All I get is : `Process finished with exit code 1`.

So, my question is : Why can't I catch this signal sent, or at least, supposed to be sent, by CLion ?

In case it could be related to my environment, I am using CLion 2018.1.5, my Toolchain is Cygwin and I am using cmake 3.10.3. I am working on Windows 10.

Comment: Program can not block the port after process exits even if you don't close sockets clearly. You can only use *async signal safe* function inside of signal handler. Are you sure that signal handler is actually getting installed? And signal handling is not preformed somewhere else as well?

Comment: Well, I guess the process does not really exits then, since I have to do :`netstat -ano | findstr :8600` to find its `pid` and then be able to kill it with `taskkill` command. The code is really short and signal is not handling anywhere else. I don't understand what you mean by "signal handler is actually getting installed" though.

Comment: Just like most of C functions, error handling for `signal` is performed in form of return code. So you must inspect the value returned and check that no error occurs. Though I don't see why would `signal` fail here.

Comment: Create a [mcve]. Do you have threads?

Comment: Also, did you attempt this in a debug session, or regular launch? It appears that CLion goes straight for `SIGKILL` in debug sessions.

Comment: I don't have threads, and in fact, this is almost every thing I have. As I said, the code is really short.

Comment: @user2079303, no I didn't since I can't catch `SIGKILL` signal

Comment: `SIGKILL` can not be cought. I think you should try running your program from normal console and try manually hitting Ctrl+C to send `SIGINT`. Why do you set handler for `SIGQUIT` instead of `SIGINT` btw?

Comment: @user2079303 I have updated my question with an even simplier example that did not work either

Comment: @VTT my bad for `SIGQUIT`, just tried few things and forgot to put it back to `SIGINT`. In fact, I hit the "stop" button of CLion, and this button is supposed to send the signal. Yes I am in normal console.

Comment: I mean you should check this code *without* clion. Maybe it sends Ctrl+C incorrectly or something.

Comment: You are probably right, will try and let you know.

Comment: @VTT It worked, so I guess the problem comes from CLion. It is supposed to send a signal, but does it incorrectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what I conclude from @VTT's help.

The provided example should work, and actually works when not using CLion. I tried on a terminal actually doing `CTRL-C` and it worked. My program received the `SIGINT` signal.

So this issue is probably a CLion bug, since the stop button is actually supposed to simulate a `CTRL-C` and send a `SIGINT` signal.

I sent a bug report to JetBrain's team, and will be waiting for their eventual feedback, and let you know.

Thank you @VTT again.

---

**EDIT :**

I did contact CLion support and they just redirected me to another similar [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-3067.) written by another CLion user. So I guess they are not going to do anything.

After some researches, I went to this [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-6434). Almost the same thing, except its saying that CLion does not kill processes correctly, which is my case.

Apparently, it's a bug due to their stop script. I found a way to make CLion actually end the process.

### WARNING !

You should consider that chaning registry options might be dangerous! Use the following solution at your own risk!

Here is what I did :

- Click on Help
- Click on Find action
- Type and select Registry
- Uncheck `run.processes.with.pty`

That's it!

> You must know that this will not allow you to catch SIGINT signal supposed to be sent by the "stop" button of CLion, but it does kill the process, unlike the stop button. Please also note that this is not the actual answer to the question, but as I was working on a programming project, I had to manually kill my server to run it again. So it solved my problem, and might also solve someone's else.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same issue and ran into the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6010232/2464662) by Employed Russian. It is not ideal, however I was able to pass SIGINT to my process and have exit gracefully (in my case that was my intention).

What I didn't like about this method is that you need to do too many steps:

1. configure the registry to send SIGINT instead of SIGSTOP (WARNING is similar to souki's answer)
2. Whenever you want to stop - > pause the process instead.
3. Send the command `handle SIGTRAP nostop noprint pass`
4. Continue the process.